# Preparing DataFrames with Transformers to run Spark ML algorithms pyspark

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Sorry this is a bit of a generic doubt rather than a very specific problem, but I have been reading and testing different pre-processing using the `Transformers` in Spark ML and some things are not entirely clear for me.

Please, correct me if I am wrong in any of my assumptions.

So, I've understood that each categorical attribute needs to be converted (indexed) to numeric values using `StringIndexer`. Then, if I wanna use Linear or Logistic Regression, this would have to be followed by `OneHotEncoder` to create a binary vector for each one of the categorical attributes. However, if I wanna use Decision Trees or Random Forests, would I need to use `VectorIndexer` or no further transformations are required? When would it be useful or necessary to use it? I haven't quite understood the usefulness of it.

For example, I am running some tests on this [dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/abalone/abalone.data):

```
M,0.455,0.365,0.095,0.514,0.2245,0.101,0.15,15
M,0.35,0.265,0.09,0.2255,0.0995,0.0485,0.07,7
F,0.53,0.42,0.135,0.677,0.2565,0.1415,0.21,9
M,0.44,0.365,0.125,0.516,0.2155,0.114,0.155,10
I,0.33,0.255,0.08,0.205,0.0895,0.0395,0.055,7
```

The last column is the value that needs to be predicted.
So this is my code for loading and pre-processing the data:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/abalone/abalone.data')
df.columns = ['Sex', 'Length', 'Diameter', 'Height', 'Whole weight', 'Schuked weight', 'Viscera weight', 'Shell weight', 'Rings']
train_dataset = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df)

column_types = train_dataset.dtypes

categoricalCols = []
numericCols = []

for column_type in column_types:
    if column_type[1] == 'string':
        categoricalCols += [column_type[0]]
    else:
        numericCols += [column_type[0]]

stages = []
for categoricalCol in categoricalCols:
    stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol=categoricalCol, outputCol=categoricalCol+"Index")
    stages += [stringIndexer]

assemblerInputs = map(lambda c: c + "Index", categoricalCols) + numericCols
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=assemblerInputs, outputCol="features")
stages += [assembler]

labelIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol='Rings', outputCol='indexedLabel')
stages += [labelIndexer]

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=stages)
pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(train_dataset)
train_dataset = pipelineModel.transform(train_dataset)
```

With this my the dataset would be ready for a Decision Forest, for example? Is there a better way to do what I did? In case I wanted to use a Logistic Regression I would only need to add a `OneHotEncoder` transformation inside my `for` loop?
For a little bit of context, I am trying to create a more or less generic code that allows me to run experiments with different datasets and different ML algorithms.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks OK. `VectorIndexer` is useful when upstream process doesn't provide [required metadata](https://github.com/awesome-spark/spark-gotchas/blob/master/06_data_preparation.md#metadata-in-ml-pipelines).